# Android 11 Scoped Storage permission (How to manage File Manager app, what about File Manager app)

Tags: android, file-manager, scoped-storage

As we know from android 11 Write external storage permission will not work, we cant access the other directories of root path of external storage, But my question is what about the File Manager App, if my app is File Manager than how do I Manage all file operation as like before.  for example, new file or folder creation, here we can not get root path access of external storage, so how to manage File Manager operation, I read in the developer site and somewhere their is option to handle that particular apps, and Google also give some way to manage that app, but how I cant find some solution, If anyone know please help me out from this.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files

Comment: It is unclear what you mean with 'manage File Manager operation'.

Comment: Thanks for your response @CommonsWare

Answer (score -1):

> > As we know from android 11 Write external storage permission will not work, we cant access the other directories of root path of external storage,

Requesting write external storage makes no sense as it is implicitly granted to your app already.

You can access all paths from getExternalStorageDirectory() and getExternalStoragePublicDirectory().

And create subdirs and files in the getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()'s